Heat equation with spherical initial condition
Let us consider the heat equation on $\mathbb R^2$, with initial condition $u_0$,
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
u_t = \Delta u & \text{in } \mathbb R^2 \times (0, +\infty),\\
u(\cdot , 0) = u_0
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
The solution of such an equation is given by the Duhamel formula
$$u(x, t) = \frac{1}{4\pi t} \int_{\mathbb R^2}e^{-|x - y|^2/4t} u_0(y) dy.$$
Moreover, we assume that the initial condition has the following form
$$u_0(x) = \tilde{u}_0(r) e^{i\theta}, \quad \text{for } x= re^{i\theta}.$$
I was wondering if it is possible to show that the solution of the heat equation with such initial condition had the same form. More precisely, can we show that
$$u(x, t) = \tilde{u}(r, t)e^{i\theta},$$
with $\tilde{u}$ solving
$$\tilde{u}_t = \tilde{u}_{rr} + \frac{1}{r}\tilde{u}_r - \frac{1}{r^2}\tilde{u} \quad \text{and} \quad \tilde{u}(0, r) = \tilde{u}_0(r).$$
However, looking at the Duhamel formula, it is not clear for me that the solution has this form. Indeed, one gets
$$u(x, t) = \frac{1}{4\pi t} \int_0^\infty\int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{-|re^{i\theta} - \rho e^{i\sigma}|^2/4t} \tilde{u}_0(\rho)e^{i\sigma} \rho d\rho d\sigma.$$
Is there a way to simplify this formula ? Is it possible to eventually get $u(x, t) = \tilde{u}(r, t) e^{i\theta}$ ?

Are you missing a ‘$-$’ in your exponential?

Yes, it's possible. Your last equation can be rewritten as
$$
u(x,t)=\frac{e^{i\theta}}{4\pi t}\int_0^{\infty}\int_0^{2\pi}\exp\left\{-\frac{r^2+\rho^2-2r\rho\cos(\sigma-\theta)}{4t}\right\}\tilde{u}_0(\rho)e^{i(\sigma-\theta)}\,\rho d\sigma d\rho. \tag{1}
$$
Since the integrand of $(1)$ is a $2\pi$-periodic function of $\sigma$, we may replace $\int_0^{2\pi}$ with $\int_{\theta}^{\theta+2\pi}$:
$$
u(x,t)=\frac{e^{i\theta}}{4\pi t}\int_0^{\infty}\int_{\theta}^{\theta+2\pi}\exp\left\{-\frac{r^2+\rho^2-2r\rho\cos(\sigma-\theta)}{4t}\right\}\tilde{u}_0(\rho)e^{i(\sigma-\theta)}\,\rho d\sigma d\rho. \tag{2}
$$
Making the substitution $\phi=\sigma-\theta$, we get
$$
u(x,t)=\frac{e^{i\theta}}{4\pi t}\int_0^{\infty}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\exp\left\{-\frac{r^2+\rho^2-2r\rho\cos(\phi)}{4t}\right\}\tilde{u}_0(\rho)e^{i\phi}\,\rho d\phi d\rho. \tag{3}
$$
The integral in $(3)$ doesn't depend on $\theta$, only on $r$ and $t$. We conclude, therefore, that $u(x,t)=e^{i\theta}\tilde{u}(r,t)$.
